# How can I pytest+monkeypatch a callable class to reusably specify the return of __call__?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am trying to write tests for classes that use Langchain's `LLMChain` class under the covers. The `LLMChain` class is callable.

```py
class MockLLMChain:
    """
    Mock LLMChain class for testing

    Example usage in a test:

    monkeypatch.setattr(langchain.chains, "LLMChain",
        MockLLMChain(desired_response='9'))
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MockLLMChain.response = "default"

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return MockLLMChain.response

def test_yes_no_classifier(yes_no_classifier, monkeypatch):

    MockLLMChain.response = {'text': '9'}

    import src.query_helpers.yes_no_classifier
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        src.query_helpers.yes_no_classifier, "LLMChain", MockLLMChain
    )

    response = yes_no_classifier.classify(
        conversation="1234", statement="The sky is blue."
    )

    assert response == 9
```

The above code results in a test error as the `MockLLMChain` response is not actually overridden, and inside the `YesNoClassifier` we are expecting `response` to be a dict.

```py
class MockLLMChain:
    """
    Mock LLMChain class for testing

    Example usage in a test:

    monkeypatch.setattr(langchain.chains, "LLMChain",
        MockLLMChain(desired_response='9'))
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.response = "default"

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.response

def test_yes_no_classifier(yes_no_classifier, monkeypatch):

    ml = MockLLMChain()
    ml.response = {'text':'default'}

    import src.query_helpers.yes_no_classifier
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        src.query_helpers.yes_no_classifier, "LLMChain", ml
    )

    response = yes_no_classifier.classify(
        conversation="1234", statement="The sky is blue."
    )

    assert response == 9
```

The above code results in an error:

```
        llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=bare_llm, prompt=prompt_instructions, verbose=verbose)
    
>       response = llm_chain(inputs={"statement": statement})
E       TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

The error suggests to me that this monkeypatching is substituting the output of the callable class (the dict) and not the modified callable class (`ml`).

Can someone suggest a way to make this `MockLLMChain` class reusable across many tests without having to hard-code the entire mocked class definition in each test just to control what the mocked class returns when it is called?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a variant of a class factory function works:

```py
def mock_llm_chain(retval):

    class MockLLMChain:
        """
        Mock LLMChain class for testing

        Example usage in a test:

        monkeypatch.setattr(langchain.chains, "LLMChain",
            MockLLMChain(desired_response='9'))
        """

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return retval
    return MockLLMChain

def test_yes_no_classifier(yes_no_classifier, monkeypatch):

    ml = mock_llm_chain({'text':'default'})

    import src.query_helpers.yes_no_classifier
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        src.query_helpers.yes_no_classifier, "LLMChain", ml
    )

    response = yes_no_classifier.classify(
        conversation="1234", statement="The sky is blue."
    )

    assert response == 9
```

This results in an expected error because internally the `YesNoClassifier` cannot handle the non-integer value of 'default'